# override pure virtual function not possible with const struct timepec*

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual, pure-virtual

Below is my Pure virtual Interface class that I want to Implement:

```
#include <time.h>
class SharedMemoryInterface
{
public:
    virtual ~SharedMemoryInterface() {}
    virtual int sem_timedwait(sem_t* sem, const struct timepsec* abs_timeout) = 0; 
};
```

Below is the implementation:

```
class SharedMemoryImpl : public SharedMemoryInterface
{
public:
    virtual int sem_timedwait(sem_t* sem, const struct timespec* abs_timeout) { return ::sem_timedwait(sem, abs_timeout); }
};
```

I get the compiler error:

```
SharedMemoryImpl.h:25:7: note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within "SharedMemoryImpl":
 class SharedMemoryImpl : public SharedMemoryInterface
SharedMemoryInterface.h:27:17: note:    virtual int SharedMemoryInterface::sem_timedwait(sem_t*, const timepsec*)
     virtual int sem_timedwait(sem_t* sem, const struct timepsec* abs_timeout) = 0;
```

The only difference seems to be in the timespec parameter, it removes the struct and the prototypes do not match anymore, why is it doing this?

Comment: Note `timepsec` versus `timespec`. Fix your typo.

Comment: Why an extra `}` in implementation?

Comment: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d5e29c82d2aac0d2- it compiled

Comment: darn, that was it, time to go home

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a typo in `SharedMemoryInterface::sem_timedwait`: you wrote `timepsec` instead of `timespec`.

Normally this would cause an error, but you used the `struct` keyword. When the compiler sees `struct timepsec`, it either finds a struct named `timepsec` (ignoring any functions with the same name) or forward-declares a new one if it doesn't find it. So, the use of `struct` masks the typo. When you spell `timespec` correctly in `SharedMemoryImpl`, of course it refers to a different type. So the pure virtual function in `SharedMemoryInterface` isn't overridden.

AFAIK, there isn't a compiler warning that catches these misspelled forward declarations. In C++, I would suggest that it's a good practice to simply avoid elaborated type specifiers, unless you really need your code to compile in both C and C++ (obviously, that's not the case here) or you need to refer to a struct/class with the same name as a function (obviously, it's bad to name things this way, but C libraries do it sometimes).